# help to parametrize $y^2 = x^3 -x^2$

Tags: elliptic-curves

I appreciate if someone could help me to parametrize this equation $y^2 = x^3 -x^2$.

Thanks in advance.
I used maple to find the solution as $(x,y) = ((t^2-1),(t(t^2-1))$

Comment: What is your question?   You should be able to verify the solution by plugging it in.

Comment: I can't verify when I plug x in y^2. I need someone to show that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you do is plug the parameterization into the equation.  You want to find that if you plug $t^2-1$ in for $x$ you get the given expression for $y$.  Unfortunately, it fails.  So 
$$ \begin {align} x^3-x^2 &=(t^2-1)^3-(t^2-1)^2\\
&=(t^2-1)^2(t^2-1-1)\\
&=(t^2-1)^2(t^2-2)\\&=y^2-2x^2 \end {align}$$
Could it be your equation is supposed to be $x^3+x^2=y^2$?